# Как передать table в textarea jQuery?

Tags: jquery, form, table, textarea

Есть страница корзины, на странице товары и их параметры формируются в таблицу **table**.

```
<table>
<thead><tr>...</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>img</td>
<td>параметр</td>
<td>input количество</td>
<td>параметр</td>
<td>параметр</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Есть кнопка "**оформить заказ**", при клике на которую открывается попап с полями имя и телефон, сделал скрытую область **textarea**, в нее нужно передать всю **table**.

На php сделал проверку **textarea minlength=>1**

При сабмите, форма ругается на пустое поле **textarea**, хотя оно не пустое и вся **table** передается туда.

Что делаю не так?

Или есть более разумный способ совершить задуманное?

```
$(document).on('click',  '.checkAndSend', function(){
var order = $('.forTableCart table').clone();
$('textarea#appending').append(order);
});
```

Comment: А вы большой оригинал, в текстовое поле пихать таблицу.

Comment: @doox911 Да, согласен, что не правильно это. Поэтому я и спросил как лучше это организовать. encodeURIComponent ?